# Code works on Powershell version 3 but not on Powershell 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

My below code works on Powershell version 3 but not on Powershell 2.

when I run `(Get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1).CounterSamples.CookedValue` on v3 I get output but not in v2

```
[System.Int32] $NumberOfSamples = 3
[System.Int32] $FreeCPUThreshold = 10
[System.Double[]] $CPUArray = @()
[System.Int32] $LoopCounter = 1


    while ($LoopCounter -lt $NumberOfSamples)
    {
        $CPUArray += (Get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1).CounterSamples.CookedValue

        $LoopCounter++
    }

    $CalculatedUsedCPU = [System.Math]::Floor( ($CPUArray | Measure-Object -average).Average)

    if ($CalculatedUsedCPU -gt $FreeCPUThreshold)
    {
        Write-Host ("Free CPU threshold (" + $FreeCPUThreshold + " %) was hit on machine: `"" + $TargetHostname + "`", with value of: " + $CalculatedUsedCPU + " %.")
    }

    else
    {
        Write-Host ("Free CPU threshold (" + $FreeCPUThreshold + " %) was hit on machine: `"" + $TargetHostname + "`", with value of: " + $CalculatedUsedCPU + " %." , "UNDER CONTROL")
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about how it "doesn't work". Is there an error, incorrect output, or something else unexpected?

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not a suitable problem description. What specifically doesn't work? What errors (if any) are you getting? If you want help here, you need to be *specific* in describing the problem you're having and in the question you're asking.

Comment: Ok.. when I run (Get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1).CounterSamples.CookedValue
on v3 I get output but not in v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that CounterSamples is actually an array, so it should be

```
(Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1).CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
```

The difference appears to be that Powershell 3.0 seems to treat an array containing a single item like the item for purposes of invoking methods and properties, for example:

```
@(1).ToBoolean($null)
```

will print True in 3.0 but yields an error in 2.0.